# Firefox Addons - Incompatible FF4+

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have an FF addon that I developed a while back that is no longer compatible with FF4+. I have found [this](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2010/11/11/making-add-on-compatible-firefox-4/) great article that explains what could possibly cause the errors.

Rather than going through each item of the list and my entire codebase is there a way to debug which areas of the addon are causing it to be incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to debug which areas of the addon are causing it to be incompatible?

Go through each item of the list and eliminate those you know you don't have to worry about due to not utilizing anything related to them, and then take the remaining ones and check your codebase. It's not like it's that long of a list, and if you've documented/commented your code well it shouldn't be too hard to find the points of contention based on the list of changes.

And, of course, the Error Console window (Go to Tools>Error Console or press Ctrl+Shift+J) is invaluable for detecting JavaScript errors, even in addons.

Comment: Yep looks like that's the only way to go. There doesn't seem to be a "tool" for this so like you say I will be going through a compatability list and running through my source code.